# OPC-UA custom node icon

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I want to display custom node icons for my opc-ua server, the icon property is part of the standard properties, as mentioned in *Part 3, Page 20*.

I am already encoding node attributes  & references with no issues. I am trying to figure out how standard properties are encoded, i can't seem to find the information in the specification.

At which part of the specification does opcua mention about encoding standard properties ? My copy of the specification is Release 1.03

Answer (score 0):

The spec says the DataType of the Icon property is `Image`.

`Image` is an abstract DataType defined in the spec. It has some subtypes defined by the spec also: `ImageBMP`, `ImageGIF`, and `ImageJPG`.

When you build your Icon property Node, set the appropriate DataType for your encoding.

Comment: i have done that, the icon still doesn't appear on the client. Could it be the opc-ua client does not support custom icons ?

Comment: Could be. Icons are entirely optional on both sides.